# How do you create a route that starts with a dot in Remix?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I just started using Remix.run and I'm trying to add a ssl certificate to my site and it requires that I make this specific path available in my app that's similar to this
`www.mypage.com/.well-known/pki-validation/blah.txt`

Unfortunately, I find that when i create a route folder in Remix that starts with a dot, it returns a 404 response. Even when i try to escape it in the name like so `[.]well-known`

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes#url-escaping

Example of what I've tried.

```
app/
├── routes/
│   ├── [.]well-known/
│   │   ├── pki-validation
│   │   ├────── blah[.]txt.tsx
│   └── about.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
└── root.tsx
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and as a workaround I could solve changing the folder to a file:

not working:

```
app/
├── routes/
│   ├── [.well-known]/
│   │   ├── file.tsx
```

working:

```
app/
├── routes/
│   ├── [.]well-known.file.tsx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to wrap more between those brackets.

```
app/
├── routes/
│   ├── [.well-known]/
│   │   ├── pki-validation
│   │   ├────── [blah.txt].tsx
│   └── about.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
└── root.tsx
```

Think i got something working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-wmuju8

Edit: seems like escaping the dot in the wellknown folder and file  is enough, so not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for validating it for me, it must be something else in my setup that is making it return a 404